# Join query is going wrong

Tags: mysql

I have two tables: the first is `travellers_details` and the second is
`user_info`.

- traveller_details table has columns id, `travel_mode`, `dep_from`, `arr_to`, `dep_date`, `user_id` and `status`.
- user_info table has columns `user_id`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `email`.

I want all records of both table join with `user_id` and I wrote following query but not correct:

```sql
$sql="SELECT * FROM `traveller_details` FULL OUTER JOIN `user_info` on
traveller_details.user_id=user_info.user_id where traveller_details.dep_from='".$this->from."' and
traveller_details.arr_to='".$this->to."' and traveller_details.dep_date='".$this->sending_date."' and
traveller_details.status='N'";
```

Comment: It's very hard to answer a question like this. Please share your tables structures', some sample data and the result you're trying to get for that sample.

Comment: Improved question formatting for more readability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL doesn't support `full outer join`, so your query definitely doesn't work.  I suspect a `left join` is sufficient:

```
SELECT *
FROM `traveller_details` td LEFT OUTER JOIN
     `user_info` ui
     ON td.user_id = ui.user_id 
WHERE td.dep_from = '".$this->from."' AND
      td.arr_to = '".$this->to."' AND
      td.dep_date = '".$this->sending_date."' AND
      td.status = 'N'";
```

If all travelers have valid user info, then an `INNER JOIN` is sufficient.

Note that table aliases make the query easier to write and to read.